# How can I process the pixels of my screen with c# in real time?

Tags: c#, image, shader, screen

I've recently had the idea to create a little app that desaturates your screen (with luminance) when you press a shorcut, and it brings back the screen to the normal colors when you press it again.

I've started learning c# some months ago exclusively in Unity, recently I've tried some shader coding and I can make the desaturation with CGPROGRAM, but I have no idea how to make an app outside of Unity or how to get the pixels of the screen and process them in real time.

I've tried some quick searching on how to do this but didn't found much, is there any resources or tips you can link me to so I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This normally requires an API close to the operating system.

For Windows, try [DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX).